# How to highlight "what's new" between two latex documents

Tags: latex

For my Master Thesis I am writing a Latex document where I must put all the research I do. This document is reviewed periodically by my thesis advisors once or twice per month. Since this is a big document I'd like to automatically highlight what's new in the document since the last revision same way like Word or Openoffice do.

So my question is, given that I have a Latex document controlled by Subversion, what is the best way to create a pdf highlighting the differences between the HEAD and a previous version?

Say that I want:

- New text in a red coloured font
- New images and tables with a light red background
- Deleted text marked as a footnote or something similar

If not all are possible, which ones could be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: OT: In many cases svn diff will suffice. You can avoid spurious differences by making small changes to your writing/editing style. Although I am going OT, I feel that this method will serve you better over the longer term, in comparison with "[a] way to create a pdf highlighting the differences."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/). It is much better than simple diff programs because it understands LaTeX and won't mark changes that are simply extra spaces, or reformatted lines in the tex file.

Comment: latexdiff is not in Texlive 2009, as it has been superseded by texdiff, the difference being that latexdiff inserts definitions into Latex's preamble, whilst you have to do this yourself with texdiff, which is better since it allows multifile documents to work, as well as Plain Tex and Context documents.  It works well, I've used it often with clients.  See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdiff/

Answer (score 1):

There are [several packages](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#revision) which could manage revisions. I'd like to use some version control system like git to manage and show changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a diff program.  I recommend [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) from Source Forge.

Answer (score 0):

i like wdiff. available on an *nix platform.

you can use

```
wdiff -w "\fbox{" -x "}" -y "\fbox{\fbox{" -z "}}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I created revdiff to build diff versions of my papers before sending them to reviewers. They have told me several times that the result was really helpfull. Hope it can be useful for you.

Find it here: http://pedromateo.github.io/revdiff-LaTeX/